# Возможно ли передать в метод объект до его инициализации? Java

Tags: java

Имеется некий класс `OtherClass`:

```
class OtherClass{
//code
}
```

Имеется основной класс `Main` и метод `method`:

```
public class Main{
    public static void method(){
        //code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Возможно ли организовать что-то наподобие этого, чтобы `до инициализации передавался экземпляр класса OtherClass в метод method()` ?

```
public class Main{
    public static void method(Object obj){
        obj = new OtherClass();
        //code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    OtherClass oc;
    method(oc);
    }
}
```

Если нет, то как поступить в этой ситуации? Ситуация такая, в методе `method` содержатся `switch-case` конструкция и в зависимости от выбора `case`, создавался бы экземпляр класса через его конструктор. Конструктор там перегружен и в зависимости от `case` вызывалось бы так `oc = new OtherClass(30, 10);` либо так `oc = new OtherClass();`.

Comment: Нельзя. Поменяйте тип возвращаемого значения с `void` на `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы с самого начала создаете пустую ссылку.
В метод передается КОПИЯ этой самой ссылки.
Эта КОПИЯ принимает адрес созданного объекта.
Поэтому адрес исходной ссылки так и останется пустым.
Возвращайте КОПИЮ, чтобы передать ее адрес исходной ссылке.

Реализация для вашего случая:

```
public static Object method(){
    Object obj = new OtherClass();
    //code
    return obj;
}
```